# Can we include our own hooks in gerrit repositories

Tags: git, gerrit

is it possible that we add our own hooks to Gerrit managed git repositories? We tried adding a pre-recieve hook to the hooks directory (which was empty by default), but the hooks are not firing!
Doesnt Gerrit support customized hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleagues pointed to the Gerrit docs: http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.2.1/config-hooks.html

> Gerrit does not run any of the standard git hooks in the repositories
>   it works with, but it does have its own hook mechanism included.